# LinkedIn Share API returning "Bad Request" error

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to implement the LinkedIn share API an I can't figure this one out, since the reply doesn't really tell what's going on.

I've implemented this simple code on my website

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key:   xxx
    authorize: true
    lang:      de_DE
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Handle the successful return from the API call
  function onSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }

  // Handle an error response from the API call
  function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  function shareToLinkedIn(){
    var payload = {
        "content": { 
            "title": "Test title",
            "description": "test description",
            "submitted-url": "http://www.someurl.com",
            "submitted-image-url": "http://someurl.com/somepic.png"
            },
            "visibility": {
                "code": "connections-only"
            }
    };

    IN.API.Raw("/people/~/shares?format=json")
      .method("POST")
      .body(JSON.stringify(payload))
      .result(onSuccess)
      .error(onError);
  }
</script>
```

I'm calling this function via an onClick-event:

```
<a id="linkedin" href="#"onClick="shareToLinkedIn()"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> LinkedIn Test</a></li>
```

But all I'm getting is the following response: `Object {errorCode: 0, message: "Invalid arguments: {S_400_BAD_REQUEST=Bad request}", requestId: "4JVTZJFVF1", status: 400, timestamp: 1467381898243}`

Comment: Did you find the problem ? I have the same here :S

Comment: Actually, yes: The problem was, that I didn't authorize the app. When I implemented this, I thought it was enough that I was logged in to LinkedIn through my browser. But you actually had to implement the Login-Button for the app as well, which then opens up a window where you have to authorize the "app" to post to your profile. (This actually made me forget about this, since it seemed overly complicated for what I was trying to do.)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the fast reply ! You should post this as your own answer and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this: You need to implement a login button on your site as well, it's not enough just to be logged in to the LinkedIn-Site.
So, on the site where you "share app" is implemented, add:

`<script type="in/Login"></script>`

After that, click the button, authorize the app and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You know, you can actually solve this problem without using the share plugin at all.  In fact, just look at the [LinkedIn Developers Homepage: "Share on LinkedIn" link](https://www.linkedin.com/developers/).  It no longer goes to the [old LinkedIn documentation](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/getting-started-js-sdk?src=aff-lilpar&veh=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&trk=aff_src.aff-lilpar_c.partners_pkw.123201_plc.adgoal%20GmbH_pcrid.449670_learning&clickid=SRPXd0wT8xyORz2wUx0Mo38TUkiwFC1dwXmmUQ0&irgwc=1), which has broken styles, broken js, broken HTML, and missing images.  It redirects to the **[Microsoft LinkedIn Share URL Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/plugins/share-plugin)**.  If the LinkedIn share plugin isn't deprecated, *it's certainly no its way there!*

You can ditch the LinkedIn Share Plugin altogether.  All you need, according to the Microsoft LinkedIn documentation, is the following...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url={url}
```

Wish you knew about these URLs changing and evolving without having to track them down yourself?  I maintain a project on GitHub to do just that.  Check us out!  [Social Share URLs](https://github.com/bradvin/social-share-urls)

[image: Social Share URLs Image]